# Restarting Kafka Streams app that is shutting down without an exception

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm using Kafka Streams v. 0.10.2.0 for streaming between topics with a simple processing. Recently I had an issue when one of the brokers went down and kafka streams app shut down and stayed down until I manually restarted it. Trying to debug this issue I can't understand from logs what exactly caused this, here is the log excerpt:

```
INFO [StreamThread-1] o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator - Revoking previously assigned partitions [topicname-3, topicname-1, topicname-2] for group streams-group
INFO [StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread - stream-thread [StreamThread-1] partitions [[topicname-3, topicname-1, topicname-2]] revoked at the beginning of consumer rebalance.
INFO [StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread - stream-thread [StreamThread-1] Closing a task's topology 0_1
INFO [StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread - stream-thread [StreamThread-1] Closing a task's topology 0_2
INFO [StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread - stream-thread [StreamThread-1] Closing a task's topology 0_3
INFO [StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread - stream-thread [StreamThread-1] Flushing state stores of task 0_1
INFO [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | streams-group] o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - Marking the coordinator 127.0.0.1:9092 dead for group streams-group
INFO [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | streams-group] o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - Discovered coordinator 127.0.0.1:9092 for group streams-group.
INFO [StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread - stream-thread [StreamThread-1] Flushing state stores of task 0_2
INFO [StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread - stream-thread [StreamThread-1] Flushing state stores of task 0_3
INFO [StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread - stream-thread [StreamThread-1] Committing consumer offsets of task 0_1
ERROR [StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread - stream-thread [StreamThread-1] Failed while executing StreamTask 0_1 due to commit consumer offsets: 
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
INFO [StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread - stream-thread [StreamThread-1] Updating suspended tasks to contain active tasks [[0_1, 0_2, 0_3]]
INFO [StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread - stream-thread [StreamThread-1] Removing all active tasks [[0_1, 0_2, 0_3]]
INFO [StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread - stream-thread [StreamThread-1] Removing all standby tasks [[]]
ERROR [StreamThread-1] o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator - User provided listener org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$1 for group streams-group failed on partition revocation
INFO [StreamThread-1] o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - (Re-)joining group streams-group
INFO [StreamThread-1] o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - Marking the coordinator dead for group streams-group
INFO [StreamThread-1] o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - Discovered coordinator for group streams-group.
INFO [StreamThread-1] o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - (Re-)joining group streams-group
INFO [StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamPartitionAssignor - stream-thread [StreamThread-1] Constructed client metadata ...
INFO [StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamPartitionAssignor - stream-thread [StreamThread-1] Completed validating internal topics in partition assignor
INFO [StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamPartitionAssignor - stream-thread [StreamThread-1] Completed validating internal topics in partition assignor
INFO [StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamPartitionAssignor - stream-thread [StreamThread-1] Assigned tasks to clients as {...=[activeTasks: ([0_0, 0_4]) assignedTasks: ([0_0, 0_4]) prevActiveTasks: ([]) prevAssignedTasks: ([]) capacity: 1.0 cost: 0.2], ...=[activeTasks: ([0_1, 0_2, 0_3]) assignedTasks: ([0_1, 0_2, 0_3]) prevActiveTasks: ([]) prevAssignedTasks: ([]) capacity: 1.0 cost: 0.30000000000000004]}.
INFO [StreamThread-1] o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - Successfully joined group streams-group with generation 17
INFO [StreamThread-1] o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator - Setting newly assigned partitions [topicname-3, topicname-1, topicname-2] for group streams-group
INFO [StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread - stream-thread [StreamThread-1] New partitions [[topicname-3, topicname-1, topicname-2]] assigned at the end of consumer rebalance.
INFO [StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamTask - task [0_1] Initializing processor nodes of the topology
INFO [StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamTask - task [0_2] Initializing processor nodes of the topology
INFO [StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamTask - task [0_3] Initializing processor nodes of the topology
INFO [StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread - stream-thread [StreamThread-1] Shutting down
INFO [StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread - stream-thread [StreamThread-1] Closing a task 0_1
INFO [StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread - stream-thread [StreamThread-1] Closing a task 0_2
INFO [StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread - stream-thread [StreamThread-1] Closing a task 0_3
INFO [StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread - stream-thread [StreamThread-1] Flushing state stores of task 0_1
INFO [StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread - stream-thread [StreamThread-1] Flushing state stores of task 0_2
INFO [StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread - stream-thread [StreamThread-1] Flushing state stores of task 0_3
INFO [StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread - stream-thread [StreamThread-1] Closing the state manager of task 0_1
INFO [StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread - stream-thread [StreamThread-1] Closing the state manager of task 0_2
INFO [StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread - stream-thread [StreamThread-1] Closing the state manager of task 0_3
INFO [StreamThread-1] o.a.k.c.p.KafkaProducer - Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms.
INFO [StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread - stream-thread [StreamThread-1] Removing all active tasks [[0_1, 0_2, 0_3]]
INFO [StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread - stream-thread [StreamThread-1] Removing all standby tasks [[]]
INFO [StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread - stream-thread [StreamThread-1] Stream thread shutdown complete
WARN [StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.i.StreamThread - Unexpected state transition from RUNNING to NOT_RUNNING
```

First of all it seems very unlikely that processing was taking a long time because it is very simple and the app was running for a couple of months with no messages like that in the logs.

Also judging from the logs kafka streams successfully rejoined the group but then suddenly it just shut down without an exception. I had two streams apps running on different machines and both were shut down at the same time when broker restarted.

How do I debug this problem? Shouldn't it throw an exception at least?
Another issue is that while streams thread shut down the rest of an app was working fine so it wasn't restarted automatically. Can I catch this somehow and restart the thread? The retention policy makes it very undesirable for a consumer to go under, how can I make the kafka streams app more reliable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say from the log. Maybe DEBUG log would reveal more information...

The only "shot in the dark" might be, that there was an error during `Initializing processor nodes of the topology`. But if there was an exception, it should be in the log actually. It could also be a bug in the library.

About monitoring your application, you have multiple options:

- you can register a `KafkaStreams#setUncaughtExceptionHandler()` to see if an exception bubble out if a `StreamThread`  and thus the thread dies
- you can register a `KafkaStreams#setStateListener()` to see if the app go into `NOT_RUNNING` state (btw: there is one know issue with `NOT_RUNNING` state in 0.10.2 and 0.11.0 -- just got fixed in `trunk`: if all threads are dead, the state might still be `RUNNING`, so you should monitor the number of threads that are still running manually)

Btw: I would recommend to upgrade to `0.10.2.1` that contains multiple important bug fixes.